# How to test flatmap when return Observable.error

Tags: unit-testing, rx-java

I am try to test `Observable.flatmap` when return `Observable.error`,but I can not find a good way to do .

```
@Override
public Observable<List<MovieInfo>> getPopMoviesFromNet(int page) {
    return Observable.just(page)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<List<MovieInfo>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<MovieInfo>> call(Integer page) {
                    try{
                        List<MovieInfo> movies = MovieOkhttp.getMovieData(page);
                        return Observable.just(movies);
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        return Observable.error(e);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I try to mock this `repository`.

```
@Test
public void getPopMoviesFromNetError() {
    Mockito.when(repository.getPopMoviesFromNet(1))
            .thenReturn(Obserable.error(new IOException()));
            //can not do 

}
```

I am new to `Mockito` and UnitTest ，but I think I do not find a good way to test `Obserable.flatmap` is that I am not good at `Rxjava`.

EXTRA: Rxjava 1.2

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution from the [video](https://youtu.be/g1bxHkkdp90?t=3006)

```
Mockito.when(repository.getPopMoviesFromNet(1))
        .thenReturn(Obserable.<List<MovieInfo>>error(new IOException()));
```

I am sorry for that i am not good at generic class.